# Change logfile handle in decorator for unittest

Tags: python, logging, decorator

I need some advice for a problem:

Ich try to do unittests which are started by a campaign runner.

Runner: HTMLTestRunner

The tests are arranged in a package (Testcases). Each testcase is a python module with a class for it. So: -> Testmodul -> TestClass -> test_funct

Now, to extend logging (different reasons like only saving logs for specific errors and starting and ending a screenrecord) I made a decorator which should handle my logfiles. So that means:

When a decorated testcase is started, The logfile handle should be set to a temporary file
During the testcase run, the logfile should be filled with ALL log-messages from the project
When the testcase is finished, the logfile should be copied to another directory (timestamp appended to name) and then the old logfile should be deleted.
So far so good, this all works fine so far, but the content of the logfile is not correct. I tried so many things. Sometimes not all logmessages are covered, sometimes it is a doubled amount of logmessages. Sometimes the messages start in the middle of the testcase. Can you maybe help me at this issue?

Initialization of logger in My Campaign:

```
def main():

    console = logging.StreamHandler()
    console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(my_format_string)
    console.setFormatter(formatter)
    logging.getLogger().addHandler(console)
    logger = logging.getLogger("campaign")
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Decorators in other module:

```
def extended_logging(func):

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):


        root = logging.getLogger("campaign")
        for hndlrs in root.handlers:
            root.removeHandler(hndlrs)
        console = logging.StreamHandler()
        console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        formatter = logging.Formatter(my_format_string)
        console.setFormatter(formatter)
        root.addHandler(console)
        filehandler = logging.FileHandler(config.LOG_FILEPATH, mode='w+')
        formatter = logging.Formatter(my_format_string)
        filehandler.setFormatter(formatter)
        root.addHandler(filehandler)
        logger.info("This should actually work")
        try:
            time.sleep(5)
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as error:  # *** This is just dummy error handling for the test 

            logger.info("An exception occured")
            logger.info("This testcase is false")
            raise Exception
        finally:

            # *** Copies and renames the temp logfile and removes it after
            save_logs(None, None, "module", "1")    
    return wrapped_func
```

Definition of TC is like this:

```
logger=logging.getLogger(f"camapaign.{__name__}")
class TestClass(unittest.Testcase):

   @extended_logging
   def test_mylittlemoduletest:
       logger.info("Doing my testcase now")
       # here smthng will be done
```

Comment: The following places look suspicious: 1. You always use same path `config.LOG_FILEPATH` for all test cases, if multiple tests are running at the same time there might be mess in this file. 2. You don't call `close` for your fileHandler.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response. It is intended behaviour to take one file for each testcase. The testcases run in a sequence. So they should always log to one temporary logfile. After finishing the testcase the logfile will be copied to another path an their it will be renamed. Now the next testcase should start the temporary logfile from begin. How can I call close to my filehandler? I searched a long time and to remove filehandlers, the command '.removeHandlers(logger)' was always said.